# Modular inverse calculation stuck

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, theory

Here is my code so far:

```
def mod_div(a, b, n): 

if gcd(b,n) != 1:
    return 'Undefined'    

for x in range(1, n):
        if b*x%n == a%n:      
            return x
```

this code takes the function gcd() which I made and returns the gcd, which i then use to calculate the inverse.  I did a search of the questions, and none of them seem to be giving me the correct answer.

My problem is this: when I do div_mod(3,2,7), the code returns 5, as it should.  However, when I do it for large numbers, such as n > 10000, it takes very long for the solution to compute because of the iteration through n to find the correct number.

I tried looking at the other questions, and in their answers, they all have a similar thing, but instead of going for i in n, they all return x%n if gcd != 1.
this does not help me,and it does not give the right answer.

For example. if I use a=12, b = 3 and n= 11 it should return 4,but all the functions I found except for mine all return 1.

I want to know if thereis a more efficient way to use eulids extended theorem other than testing each n, and hoping one works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that the Extended Euclidean Algorithm solves this task. However you don't need to call it `n` times - you only need it once. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Here is an imperative python algorithm from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

```
def egcd(a, b):
    x,y, u,v = 0,1, 1,0
    while a != 0:
        q, r = b//a, b%a
        m, n = x-u*q, y-v*q
        b,a, x,y, u,v = a,r, u,v, m,n
    return b, x, y

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        return None  # modular inverse does not exist
    else:
        return x % m
```

O(1) space and around O(log n) time in the worst case.

Now, to divide modulo `n`, we have by definition

```
def moddiv(a, b, n):
    binv = modinv(b, n)
    if not binv:
        return None
    return a * binv % n
```

Comment: thank you.  however, for my test cases, a,b,c = 14,67,88 should output  58, but in this case, when i put a and m in the modinv function, it returns None rather than 58.  I am having a hard time understanding why. also, i noticed you used a in your answer for modinv where I used  b.  i don't understand why.

Comment: the inverse of `a` is such element b that `a * inv = 1 mod m` so you only need two parameters. I guess you are looking for `a * inv = b` but than it is enough to multiply the result by `b` and take `mod m`.

Comment: Ps. Thank you for accepting the answer. Know however that there is nothing wrong if you accept just when things become clear ;)

Comment: thank you for clarifying. I accepted your answer because the algorithm makes sense, its just that there must be something missing.  i still cannot get a,b,c = 14,67,88 to output 58.   Would you mind explaining this part?

Comment: I mixed the notation in the previous comment, sorry. So you have `a=14,b=67,n=88`. You first need to invert `b` modulo `n`. it turns out that `modinv(67,88) = 67`. Now you simply multiply `a` by inverted `b` so you get `14*67 mod 88 = 58`. I will add `mod_div` function to the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45505/discussion-between-user3205701-and-lukasz-kidzinski)